# Mirroring a Linux Machine Onto a Linux Laptop (via HDMi cable)?

Tags: x11, display

I have an old Linux laptop I'd like to repurpose as a mirror of my main Linux Desktop.

Basically, it'd be nice to

1. Plug an HDMi cable from my main machine into my laptop.
2. The laptop then mirrors my main screen with no lag (due to using an HDMi cable as opposed to WiFi VNC).
3. The laptop's keyboard/mouse also "just work" when interacting with my main screen.

Is this possible?

Comment: HDMI connectors on computers are traditionally outputs

Comment: Is there another connector I could use instead?

Comment: depends, does the laptop have a video INPUT "connector"

Comment: Would an ethernet cable work with VNC, as a way to significantly reduce the WiFi lag associated with WiFi VNC?